# How to find enabled modules in Magento 1?

Tags: third-party-module, magento-1.4

I am creating a list of **Enabled 3rd party modules in magento 1**.

What is the quick way to find them & get it in note ?

Thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Module enable or disable file here

> app/etc/modules/Vendor_Module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
<Vendor_Module>
<active>true</active>
<codePool>local</codePool> // here local or community 
</Vendor_Module>
</modules>
</config>
```

You could browse through `app/code/local` and `app/code/community`. For each module go to `etc/` and open `config.xml`.

and other way..

> System -> Configuration -> Advanced -> Disable Modules Output

Comment: Sir, i asked how can quickly determine which module is 3rd party & enabled , so i can create a list of it.

Comment: @HamendraSunthwal i have updated my answer and other way to check `core_resource` table and other way Log in to your Magento Admin Panel. Navigate to System > Configuration > Advanced > Advanced see the list of the installed extensions/modules along with their status.

Comment: Thanks, i can see an extension name as "Enterprise_Banner" is it core module of M1 ?

Comment: @HamendraSunthwal may be it is enterprise edition module you look in core file and above like available (https://prnt.sc/vbtoug) or if third party module then those company name available if extension make properly :)

Comment: Great, Thankyou. I suggest you add this to answer so that other magento users can easily find all modules at a page.  System -> Configuration -> Advanced -> Disable Modules Output